# Emacs auto fill on period

Tags: text-editing, fill-paragraph, auto-fill-mode

How can I tweak Emacs auto-fill to fill when a period is inserted?

For example, with a `(setq fill-column 10)` the following will auto-fill when I press the space after "fill".

```
;; good fill

;; good
;; fill on
```

This example doesn't fill when I press the period.  I have to invoke
`fill-paragraph` manually

```
;; bad fillllllllllllllllll.

;; bad
;; fillllllllllllllllll.
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The elisp manual [section](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Auto-Filling.html#Auto-Filling) about auto-filling describes the
`auto-fill-chars` variable.

> -- Variable: auto-fill-chars
>
> ```
>  A char table of characters which invoke ‘auto-fill-function’ when
>  self-inserted—space and newline in most language environments.
>  They have an entry ‘t’ in the table.
> ```

About char tables it [says](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Char_002dTables.html#Char_002dTables):

> A char-table is much like a vector, except that it is indexed by
>   character codes.  Any valid character code, without modifiers, can be
>   used as an index in a char-table.  You can access a char-table’s
>   elements with ‘aref’ and ‘aset’, as with any array.

So you could simply do:

```el
(aset auto-fill-chars ?. t)
```

to add the `.` character to the ones triggering auto filling.

Comment: Two times the same answer does not make much sense. So I delete mine.

Comment: @Tobias Oh yes you were 7 minutes ahead of me... it would be nice that SX shows information such as "someone is currently writing an answer" to avoid such "clashes".